# Isn't it unsafe to disable antivirus scanning for directories specific to Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, security, antivirus

Android Studio recently detected that my antivirus may be significantly slowing down the project build speed because it scans files generated by Gradle. Android Studio's related article on [antivirus impact](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config?utm_source=android-studio#antivirus-impact) suggests adding exceptions for scanning the following directories:

[image]

However, I'm hesitant to do this. Wouldn't it be possible for malware to install itself under these directories in order to bypass detection, assuming whoever designed it is aware that these directories may be listed as exceptions?

Comment: You are not prone to viruses if you prevent from getting one.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you clarify?

Comment: Your question is more opinion-based than having a proper answer. If you really want to prevent virus attacks you can use a linux OS for AS/ you can compromise on the speed/ risk by adding exceptions. Let's say the probability of a virus attack there is 1% to nil currently..

Comment: @AlexH This message is a standard message shown to all Android Studio users on Windows systems that use Windows Defender as virus scanner. If you don't encounter a significant delay you can just ignore this message.

Comment: @Robert I do encounter a significant delay of sometimes ~5 minutes, so I was hoping to add those exceptions.

Comment: @AlexH You can use [Microsoft Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to identify which elements cause the delay. Then only exclude them.